# Office Interop changing return type between projects

Tags: c#, .net, interop, office-interop

I am using the Office 15 Interop in two projects. One is a 2017 style project targeting .Net 4.6.2, and the other is a normal .Net 4.6.2 project.

When referencing the IRibbonControl interface, the return type for context changes from `object` to `dynamic`. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribboncontrol.context.aspx) says it should return an `object`.

2017 csproj, showing the return type as `object`:
[image]

Normal .Net 4.6.2, showing the return type as `dynamic`:
[image]

The library I am referencing is exactly the same, what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens automatically when Embed Interop Types is set to its default value true. (To allow late binding)

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/walkthrough-office-programming)

To test you can set embed interop types to false on your interop assemblies and then restart vs/reload your project to see the difference in the type